# How to rename a UIViewController and its xib

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using **`iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2`**. In my project i have a `UIViewController` with `xib`. Now i want to give **seperate name** for `UIViewController` and `xib`.

Is it Possible?

After changing the name of `UIViewController` the controllers showing warning and i can not connect connect controllers to this class.

Comment: Have you renamed both the UIViewController class and its XIB? or just the class?

Comment: Do you want to rename both the class and the xib?

Comment: ya i want to rename both(must be different name).

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve?

viewController.h
viewController.m
viewController_nameChanged.xib

Comment: Why do you want to do it BTW? just curious!

Comment: How did you rename your UIViewController class file names?

Comment: Actually i just given a test name for my uiviewcontroller. That was not the correct name to be used in my project. After coding i tried to change the name. But the controllers showing some warnings.

Comment: I changed file name and interface name.

Comment: What warning message you are getting after changed file name interface name.

Comment: Not warning messages, but warning symbols when we right click FILES OWNER.

Answer (score 17):

Within your header file `(SomeViewController.h)`, highlight the class name and from Xcode menu > Edit > Refactor > Rename

And follow the on screen instructions.

Good Luck.

Comment: Its about renaming class files and .xib with separate names.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming a class file names and interface files are **possible**. However, renaming class name by refactor option on Xcode is appreciated than doing it manually.

> For refactoring GOTO: "symbol navigator(next to project navigator)">>
>   right click on your file name >> "REFACTOR">> RENAME.

Having different names for classes and interface do not bring up issues, however its the standard to keep the interface file name same as that of the corresponding class files.

Comment: Now it showing errors.

Comment: It showing errors where ever i used this class name. Error :"can not find interface declaration".

Comment: Did you refactor and still still see the old names?

Comment: without using refractor i changed the class file name, interface name, and in xib file. Now it is working. Is it a proper way?

Answer (score 2):

You just change the .h and .m file names by click on those files. What ever new name you gave to those files use that name while importing those files other than that don't change those name any where. try it once..

Answer (score 1):

> After changing the name of UIViewController the controllers showing
>   warning and i can not connect connect controllers to this class.

Find the code where you're instantiating the view controller. It should look something like:

```
MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:... bundle:...];
```

When you find that line, look at the values you're passing for the nib name and bundle. Chances are, you'll need to change the nib name that you're passing in. Either you're passing an incorrect name, or you're passing `nil`. If if the first case, simply correct the name. If you're passing `nil`, again, just change that to reflect the actual name of the .xib file. (It's common to use `nil` because `UIViewController` will use the class name as the nib name if you pass in nil, so `nil` is a handy shortcut.)

Comment: I passed xib name and nil respectively.

Comment: Also remember to update the class of the view controller inside the .xib file. The `File's Owner` proxy icon represents the view controller -- select it and set it's class to the view controller's new class name.